# Set referer in node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following peace of code that runs in browser:

```
getCountries(): Promise<ICountry[]> {
    return fetch(options.baseUrl + "/countries", {
        headers: {
            Apikey: options.apiKey,
            Referer: options.referer
        }
    }).then(res => res.json())
}
```

It works totally fine: I get an JSON result back.

But if I do this exactly same, or I guess equivalent code, in node.js with `node-fetch` I get an `401` status code from the API point.

This fetch is made in node.js

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
getCountries(): Promise<ICountry[]> {
    return fetch(options.baseUrl + "/countries", {
        headers: {
            Apikey: options.apiKey,
            Referer: options.referer
        }
    }).then(res => res.json())
}
```

I guess there is an problem with the `Referer` when i try to fetch from Server to Server.

Is it possible to change the referrer manually?

Also at their documentation they say due to nature of nodejs the `referrer` is not implemented

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#class-request

Comment: 401 means Unauthorised, which should not be caused by a wrong (or missing) referer. More likely your api key is wrong or some other `Authentication` header is missing.

Comment: @Bergi thank you. but i am sure its the referer since its an part of the authentication. For authentication i need the API key, witch is valid i am sure, and the referer. My guess is that in the browser the referer is `www.mydomain.com` but in node.js its actually the server IP and not the domain

Comment: Notice that node-fetch's `Request` class not having a `.referrer` property does not preclude you from sending the header manually. It just means they cannot automatically set it when creating a new `Request` since node.js does not have a browsing context.

Comment: Wait are you saying your `options.referer` is not `www.mydomain.com`, but you did set it to your server IP?

Comment: @Bergi `options.referer` is `www.mydomain.com`. On the page where i fetch the data i can only set domains, no IPS

Comment: Try using a http proxy to debug what headers nodejs is actually sending (and compare them to the working request from your browser). Also notice that a typical browser will send a lot more than just those two, maybe the API expects something else.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for that proxy hint i will try it

Comment: does it also use something like cookie which you also need to set in nodejs?

Comment: @Bergi is it actually possible to use puppeteer to simulate an browser request?

Comment: Possible, sure, but totally unnecessary. First try looking in the browser devtools for what headers it is sending exactly (possibly case sensitive) and replicate all of those.